# infineon TC1796 DMA access

Tags: dma, infineon, tricore

I'm already using DMA+SSC in one of the projects I'm working on, but I'm having trouble using the same configuration in another project. The problem is that in the second project I get DMA errors ME0DER/ME0SER related to DMA access to certain address spaces. The error exists even though all possible access permissions are given (DMA_ME0AENR=0xFFFFFFFF; and DMA_ME0ARR = 0x0000E0E0;). When comparing the working and non-working project, I found the following - the buffer of the working project is located in an address space starting with 0xA1000000, while the buffer of the non-working project is located in an address space starting with 0xD0000000. Unfortunately, at this stage of working on the project, I cannot modify the linker file and move all variables to the address space starting with 0xA1000000.

Question - can the DMA access addresses starting with 0xD0000000 and if so - how to enable it.